# Android TableLayout Alignment

Tags: android, alignment, android-tablelayout

I have Layout XML Like this. This is inside LinearLayout.

```
       <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" Hello world"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:background="#009900"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" v1.0"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="#009900"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </TableRow>     
    </TableLayout>
```

I want to display the row like this:

```
 [ Title                     v1.0 ]
```

But it displays like this:

```
 [ Title  v1.0                    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" RECSOLU Campus"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009900"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="v1.0"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="#009900"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </TableRow>     
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: The weight is used to distribute the remaining empty space

Comment: Can you remove the images please? I don't want the name displayed here. I should have changed before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) inside your TableRow:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
        androidLalignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" RECSOLU Campus"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="#009900"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <TextView
        androidLalignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" v1.0"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#009900"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLAyout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark">
       <------- keep this in relative layout
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" RECSOLU Campus"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="#009900"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" v1.0"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#009900"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
          ------ relative layout ends here>
    </TableRow>
```